# Further looking into "Avoid context.sync in loops"

Tags: office-js, word-addins

Article [Avoid using the context.sync method in loops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/correlated-objects-pattern) renders incredible help on the Word add-in I am developing. I see huge performance improvement after adopting the technique introduced in this article.

This really made my day. Now there is only one sync-loop left that I am not sure how to deal with it. Here is the sample code. The culprit function with context.sync() runs inside a loop, forming the sync-loop that drives me nuts. Any idea how to optimize it? For some reason, the two functions cannot be merged.

```
async function testFunc (ranges: Word.RangeCollection) {
  for (let i=0; i<1000; i++) {
    await culprit(ranges.items[i]);
  }
}
async function culprit (range: Word.Range) {
  range.load("text");
  await range.context.sync();
}
```

Comment: Try loading in a loop, context sync then read the actual text in a second loop.

Comment: As @blackening suggests, cut the `await range.context.sync();` line out of `culprit` and insert it immediately after the line that _calls_ `culprit`.

Comment: @blackening Assuming your suggestion works, please make it an Answer instead of a comment, so it counts as answered in Stack's statistics.

Comment: @RickKirkham Thanks. Was hesitant to recommend something without testing. Haven't worked on office-js for ages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try loading in a loop, context sync then read the actual text in a second loop.

(Note: Not tested, but seems to have positive feedback in the comments.)

Basically:

```
async function testFunc (ranges: Word.RangeCollection) {
  for (let i=0; i<1000; i++) {
    ranges.items[i].load('text');
  }
  await context.sync()
  for (let i=0; i<1000; i++) {
    // read the text here
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The actual code of testFunc in my situation has three level of loops and the culprit function is called in the most inner loop. Each level of loop has additional code with variables. Following your suggestion which uses the technique as described in the article, I finally restructured my code to drag the sync() out of the three levels of loops. Thanks to the article and your suggestion, I've mastered the technique introduced in this article.